# HTML inline SVG on SVG File

Tags: svg

I am trying to implement an interactive floor plan on my Webapp.
Therefore I have an SVG file (building.svg) with all the rooms. Also there are multible views defined in my building.svg:

```
<defs>
  <view id="ground-floor" viewBox=0 0 2000 2000">
    <title>Ground Floor</title>
  </view>
  <view id="upper-floor1" viewBox=0 10000 2000 2000">
    <title>Upper Floor 1</title>
  </view>
</defs>
```

I wan't the building.svg imported in my HTML code so that I can easily switch between the viewBoxes by adding the view id e.g.:

```
<img src="building.svg" width="2000">
or
<img src="building.svg#ground-floor" width="2000">
or
<img src="building.svg#upper-floor1" width="2000">
```

The problem is, I have SVG Elements (Desk) that should be directly coded into the HTML but on the same time should be on the imported SVG.

I tryed implementing it like this:

```
<svg height="1000" width="2000">
  <image href="building.svg#ground-floor" width="2000"></image>
  <rect id=desk1 x=0 y=0 width=100 height=200></rect>
</svg>
```

but then they are on the same level and chanching the the viewBox (`href="building.svg#upper-floor"`) of the imported SVG doesn't affect the the viewBox of the SVG, the Desk is on.